# Scrollable Dropup Menu in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[image]My Dropup looks like this ->

```
<div class="dropup">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                {{selectList.selectedListItem}}
        <div class="ripple-container"></div>
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="list in roleList" href="#" ng-value="list.role" name="{{list.role}}" ng-click="update(list.role, list._id)" id="{{list.role}}" ng-model="selectList" name="selectedList">{{list.role}}</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I am using CSS on dropup-menu as ->

```
overflow: scroll;
max-height: 200px;
```

But it doesn't work for me. 
**Any other solution ?**

**Update**
After Adding this Css to dropdown-menu- >

```
overflow: scroll;
max-height: 200px !important;
```

My dropdown-menu now looks like without scrollable->

[image: Updated_DropUp_Image]

Comment: What do you mean by **It doesn't work**?

Comment: Add working fiddle.

Comment: is `dropdown-menu` your own class or third party css class like boootstrap or material design? You can try `max-height: 200px !important`

Comment: @bookmarker , `dropdown-menu` is bootstrap class and after adding css ->  `max-height: 200px !important;overflow:scroll` , my dropdown menu only shows upper 4 list items with no scrollable.

Comment: once remove `overflow: scroll;` and add `overflow-y: scroll;` i hope it will do.

Comment: @nivas , The issue is still same after adding this code -> `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: If you want scroll you need to provide height and overflow as scroll in css properties that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your outer most div add this in style attribute

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="height: 200px;overflow: auto;">
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of display should be changed

instead

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="list in roleList" href="#" ng-value="list.role" name="{{list.role}}" ng-click="update(list.role, list._id)" id="{{list.role}}" ng-model="selectList" name="selectedList">{{list.role}}</a>
   </div>
```

use

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-dropUp">
   <li><a class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="list in roleList" href="#" ng-value="list.role" name="{{list.role}}" ng-click="update(list.role, list._id)" id="{{list.role}}" ng-model="selectList" name="selectedList">{{list.role}}</a></li>
 <ul>
```

then apply

```
.scrollable-dropUp{
   overflow: scroll;       /*overflow-x and overflow-y*/
   max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: The issue is still same @chaitra