# How to create dropup in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, uitextfield

How to create Auto Complete TextField in Flutter

The user start typing in field and the suggestions should come in a dropdup under the field with limit of 5 suggestions.

Comment: You can use searchDelegant

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [AutoComplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html) widget which is built-in Flutter.

You can watch this [video](https://youtu.be/-Nny8kzW380) from Widget of the Week series on Flutter Channel at Youtube.

> AutoComplete is a widget for helping the user make a selection by entering some text and choosing from among a list of options.

Here is a minimal code example from the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const AutocompleteExampleApp());

class AutocompleteExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutocompleteExampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Autocomplete Basic'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: AutocompleteBasicExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AutocompleteBasicExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutocompleteBasicExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const List<String> _kOptions = <String>[
    'aardvark',
    'bobcat',
    'chameleon',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<String>.empty();
        }
        return _kOptions.where((String option) {
          return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      onSelected: (String selection) {
        debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Moaz Thank you for helping, But i need a dropup menu not dropdown

Comment: I'm confused with your "dropup" and "dropdup 'under' the field", may i know what are you trying to make? and why AutoComplete widget didn't work for you?

Comment: @Vinodh I have the same question of Mochamad Nizwar Syafuan, can you please clarify the UI you want to implement?

Comment: Check this link once    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930162/scrollable-dropup-menu-in-angular-js

Comment: Aha, that's clear now, check this gallery of `AutoComplete` packages https://fluttergems.dev/autocomplete/, it might help you.